# AES-128 Encryption/Decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to learn more about how AES works by implementing the algorithm described on this link http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf. I have both of the encryption and decryption down, and I know for sure my encryption is correct as there are examples provided in the link that I used to test the code. However, I'm not sure of how to test if my decryption algorithm is working correctly. **The problem I'm having is that my AES implementation isn't working for a 16B input (it returns garbage). Yet, it is working for a 25KB input. Also, it is working in the sense that it accurately encrypts and decrypts most of the file, except for the bytes at the beginning and the bytes at the end of the file.** Unfortunately, I currently don't have access to the entire code (I do remember bits and pieces if needed) to post on here. I was hoping to see if someone would have an idea of what might be the problem based on my description. I'm not quite understanding how the file could mostly be decrypted besides the beginning and ending bytes, as this is supposedly in ECB mode, thus shouldn't the entire file be garbage instead of just the beginning and the end (since ECB takes in one block of input and output a block of output of the same size).

Comment: Are you padding your input if it's not a multiple of the block size?

Comment: s/EBC/ECB/ (Electronic Code Book)

Comment: @AlanStokes noted and fixed.

Comment: @Buddy Yes, I am padding my inputs to a multiple of 16 to accommodate for the possible varying input size.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really using CBC mode and the iv is not the same, probably just picking up garbage for the iv. See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

The incorrect bytes at the end may be a padding issue. How are you dealing with input to be encrypted that is not a multiple of the block size in length?

Comment: That's the problem though. I'm not using an IV nor am I XOR my ciphertext with the next plaintext input. I'm for certain I am using ECB as I'm just copying the input to a state array, encrypt it, transfer that to an out array, and then repeat the process. There isn't any chaining.

Comment: You do not mention padding, how are you handling that? What you need to do is getting 16-bytes, 20-bytes and 32-bytes working, these are the simple cases. Get reference good encryption for another source and compare, is either encryption or decryption correct? Pick one that is broken work on it. Add sample input and output to the question in hex.

Comment: Ah my apology. The reason why I did not mention padding because I thought it was common knowledge to know that both ECB and CBC requires padding unless you try to implement cyphertext stealing, but that also comes with its own cons. I did implement padding into my code, and I did it by rounding up the length of the file to the nearest multiple of 16 (since the input block size for AES that I'm using is 16 bytes). Afterward, I decrypt the ciphertext and only output up to the un-padded length of the original file.

Comment: When using PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding then padding must always be added so if the data size to be encrypted is already a multiple of the blocks size (AES 16-bytes) a full block of padding must be added. See [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).